# I get an Exec format error when trying to run a Python script in PHP. Why?

Tags: python, php

I am trying to run a Python script within PHP and I have been troubleshooting this for about a day or more, and I checked my error log and figured out the exact error. This is the error:

```
sh: 1: 3.8/bin/python3: Exec format error
```

Why am I getting this error? This is my code along with the exec:

```
<?php
    $command = '3.8/bin/python3 googleNewsScraper.py CNN';
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $status;
    echo $output;
?>
```

I have tried `json_decode` which should help. I am wondering if printing the output from the function I am running in python:

```
print(searchGNews(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Question: Does this work for the output? When I do json_decode that does nothing, but when I do json_encode it just returns null, and when I echo it without anything, just the variable, it doesnt put anything on the page. Why could this happen? When I run it on the command line with `php index.php` the entirety of the json object is echo'd to the command line.

Edit: The error has changed and no longer includes all the stuff